# asp.net 4.5 login web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am building a solution where I am planning to have a front-end website communication with a web API (Rest) which in turn will communication with back-end systems such as DBs, internal company systems etc ...

The Web API will be use to communicate between the front-end and back-end but now, how can I handle the login features?

I'm using ASP.net 4.5 for both the Web API and the front-end website.

I can see the Identity module (framework?library? not sure about the naming) for login is fairly easy to use when we connect directly to a DB but how do I implement it with a Web API?

Do I need to create a UserStore to communicate with the Web API?
Then a normal UserManager to handle Users and communicate with the custom UserStore?

Basically, what I'd like is to have the website use the Web API with "GetLogin(Login, password)" for example.
The WebAPI would return the login detail to the website.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your question is not detailed enough to be answered. Take a look at the [Authorize] Annotation for your controller actions. Here are some docs on that: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security

Comment: Nils, what do you think I should add?

Comment: You need to read how this all works together: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api In your Controllers you add a dataannotation for authorization: '[Authorize]' this will only allow authenticated users to get the result.

Comment: Nils, sorry for the time I took to reply. I already had that in place but anyways, I managed to make it work. THank you!

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the documentation?
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

Comment: Thanks atika, it is very helpful. I think I can use most of it but then I need to figure out how to separate API and website. And also how to make it work with custom DB structures ...

Comment: Why do you want to use WebApi by the way? It sounds more like you want to do MVC5 razor... that vs template provides a lot more insights and is easier to adapt to.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not familiar with MVC5 Razor ... I will look it up! My original ID was to separate the front-end (website) and the "module" that connects to the DB and other systems so that's why I thought of Web API. Until recently, the industry I worked in was extensively using ASP.net 2.0 and I'm trying to catch-up too ...